# Making changes to website

Tags: css, unix, github, web

I am having a problem dealing with a website and trying to make changes to it.

First of all, let's say that my website is www.example.com. I downloaded Putty, went to the session, and used the host name (or IP address) to be www.example.com and used the connection type to be SSH. I logged into my account with my username and password I have from the website admins and have myName@example:~$.

Then, I went to github.com. This place is where the website's git repository is located at and my admins told me to go there. I cloned the repository to my unix account and currently have a website url of www.example.com/~myName/

In putty, I have some of the css code for the website and wanted to change some part of the website. So in order to do that, I downloaded WinSCP and used that to transfer the css file of the website to my laptop, make a change to the css code, and then transfered the new code into putty account.

I can see the change on my putty account when I do **less filename.css** but when I try to log on to my account website of www.example/~myName/ , the change does not appear. In order to fix this problem, am I supposed to do something dealing with github.com and make a new branch or something to the repository I am working on, or do I need to do something else? Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using WinSCP for your changes, you should do the following :

1. Install a web server on your laptop (check for WAMP on Windows)
2. Clone your Github repository on your laptop (in `C:/wamp/www` if you are on Windows)
3. Now, you can make changes on your laptop (and `less` them) and see them on `http://localhost/`

When you are satisfied with your modifications you can do the following :

1. Push on your repository from your laptop to send the changes to Github
2. Log on your server
3. Pull the changes from Github on your server
4. Now you can access your website with the applied changes `www.example/~myName/`

This is the proper way of using a configuration management system.